# i need a mysql group by query to return hourly entry from a datetime column for each employee in a single row per employee

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by

My mysql query :

```
SELECT person,
IF((HOUR(datenew))= 9, COUNT(id),'') AS `9-10`,
IF((HOUR(datenew)) = 10, COUNT(id),'') AS `10-11`,
IF((HOUR(datenew)) = 11, COUNT(id),'') AS `11-12`,
IF((HOUR(datenew)) = 12, COUNT(id),'') AS `12-13`,
IF((HOUR(datenew)) = 13, COUNT(id),'') AS `13-14`,
IF((HOUR(datenew)) = 14, COUNT(id),'') AS `14-15`,
IF((HOUR(datenew)) = 15, COUNT(id),'') AS `15-16`,
IF((HOUR(datenew)) = 16, COUNT(id),'') AS `16-17`,
IF((HOUR(datenew)) = 17, COUNT(id),'') AS `17-18`,
IF((HOUR(datenew)) = 18, COUNT(id),'') AS `18-19`,
IF((HOUR(datenew)) = 19, COUNT(id),'') AS `19-20`,
IF((HOUR(datenew)) = 20, COUNT(id),'') AS `20-21`,
IF((HOUR(datenew)) = 21, COUNT(id),'') AS `21-22`,
COUNT(*) FROM mydatatable WHERE mydate = '2018-01-18' GROUP BY person,HOUR(datenew)
```

My Current Query Output :

[image]

MY DESIRED OUTPUT :

[image]

I will be rendering the report using PHP.

Comment: I feel like your problem is in php code - post your loop please ;-)

Comment: why don't do a simple query and prepare group with php?

Comment: @Alex The PHP part is not yet coded :-) We are taling about mysql query here... once we get the desired query output then it would be rendered using php

Comment: @olibiaz I just need to render the output. Need to to it through mysql for better performance of the report page

Comment: Nobody ever needs this. Handle issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to `GROUP BY ...,HOUR(datenew)` but just `person`

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b93760/1

```
SELECT person,
SUM(HOUR(datenew)=9) AS `9-10`,
SUM(HOUR(datenew)=10) AS `10-11`,
SUM(HOUR(datenew)=11)  AS `11-12`,
SUM(HOUR(datenew)=12)  AS `12-13`,
COUNT(*) 
FROM mydatatable 
WHERE mydate = '2018-01-18' 
GROUP BY person
```

Comment: Thanks.... I too got it with  COUNT(CASE WHEN HOUR(datenew)= 9 THEN id END) AS `9-10`

Answer (score 0):

Using Derived table, should be

```
select 
x.person,
sum(`9-10`) as `9-10`,
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
 from 
(
SELECT person,
IF((HOUR(datenew))= 9, COUNT(id),'') AS `9-10`,
IF((HOUR(datenew)) = 10, COUNT(id),'') AS `10-11`,
IF((HOUR(datenew)) = 11, COUNT(id),'') AS `11-12`,
IF((HOUR(datenew)) = 12, COUNT(id),'') AS `12-13`,
IF((HOUR(datenew)) = 13, COUNT(id),'') AS `13-14`,
IF((HOUR(datenew)) = 14, COUNT(id),'') AS `14-15`,
IF((HOUR(datenew)) = 15, COUNT(id),'') AS `15-16`,
IF((HOUR(datenew)) = 16, COUNT(id),'') AS `16-17`,
IF((HOUR(datenew)) = 17, COUNT(id),'') AS `17-18`,
IF((HOUR(datenew)) = 18, COUNT(id),'') AS `18-19`,
IF((HOUR(datenew)) = 19, COUNT(id),'') AS `19-20`,
IF((HOUR(datenew)) = 20, COUNT(id),'') AS `20-21`,
IF((HOUR(datenew)) = 21, COUNT(id),'') AS `21-22`,
COUNT(*) FROM mydatatable WHERE mydate = '2018-01-18' GROUP BY person,HOUR(datenew) 
) x

group by x.person
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use a (fake) aggregation function eg: min() for group the rows in a single row

```
SELECT person,
  min(IF((HOUR(datenew))= 9, COUNT(id),'')) AS `9-10`,
  min(IF((HOUR(datenew)) = 10, COUNT(id),'')) AS `10-11`,
  min(IF((HOUR(datenew)) = 11, COUNT(id),'')) AS `11-12`,
  min(IF((HOUR(datenew)) = 12, COUNT(id),'')) AS `12-13`,
  min(IF((HOUR(datenew)) = 13, COUNT(id),'')) AS `13-14`,
  min(IF((HOUR(datenew)) = 14, COUNT(id),'')) AS `14-15`,
  min(IF((HOUR(datenew)) = 15, COUNT(id),'')) AS `15-16`,
  min(IF((HOUR(datenew)) = 16, COUNT(id),'')) AS `16-17`,
  min(IF((HOUR(datenew)) = 17, COUNT(id),'')) AS `17-18`,
  min(IF((HOUR(datenew)) = 18, COUNT(id),'')) AS `18-19`,
  min(IF((HOUR(datenew)) = 19, COUNT(id),'')) AS `19-20`,
  min(IF((HOUR(datenew)) = 20, COUNT(id),'')) AS `20-21`,
  min(IF((HOUR(datenew)) = 21, COUNT(id),'')) AS `21-22`,
COUNT(*) FROM mydatatable 
WHERE mydate = '2018-01-18' 
GROUP BY person
```

Comment: Error Code: 1111
Invalid use of group function